# In what order should I call ANALYZE and VACUUM in an SQLite3 database?

Tags: sqlite, vacuum

In what order should I call `ANALYZE` and `VACUUM` in an SQLite3 database? What is the difference if there is any? My use case is to create a database for lookup, so I fill it with data, call `ANALYZE` and `VACUUM` and then never modify the database again.

Insight about whether the order matters for other databases like PostgreSQL and others is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyze creates system tables (named sqlite_stat? (where ? is a number)) that are used, if they exist, by the query planner when a query is run to try to optimize queries.

Analyze has little bearing on what VACUUM does, which is akin to defragmentation of a disk drive, in that it reloads the database freeing unused space (pages).

In your case, I don't think it matters which is run first as the VACUUM is unlikely to reduce the size of the sqlite_stat? tables. However, in theory VACUUM should be run last. If you are providing a read only database then you should be running both prior to putting the database into it's final place.